# Windows 8 tile notification from localhost

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, tile

I am developing a simple app for windows 8. In My app I want the start tile to show images from local host that I ship with my app. 
for example I have kept my images on  /images/tile1.jpg like wise.
and my xml code is

```
<tile>
<visual>
    <binding template="TileWideImage">
        <image id="1" src ="http://localhost/images/tile1.jpg" />
    </binding>
</visual>
```

which is present at /tile1.xml likewise

and my default.js code is

```
    // For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;
                var recurrence = notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.halfHour;


                var urls = [
                    new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://localhost/tile1.xml"),
                    new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://localhost/tile2.xml"),
                    new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://localhost/tile3.xml"),
                    new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://localhost/tile4.xml")
                ];


                notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().enableNotificationQueue(true);
                notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().startPeriodicUpdateBatch(urls, recurrence);

            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };


  app.start();
})();
```

I am just unable to figure out what's wrong with the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't.  Loopback is not permitted, so your app won't pass certification if you're using a localhost service.

Can you deliver the images with the app itself? Alternatively, set up an external service to host your images and tiles.  You really only need something like Windows Azure blob storage, don't even need to host a web service.

Lastly, you'll want to make sure you ALWAYS include a square tile image. The user always has control, so they may choose not to display your app as a wide tile.